# What is the part of code that processing video in Dash.JS?

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, dash.js

Dash.js code: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/tree/7ad55a21b24a673dd55c5c4ae08367753bb7baaa

I'm cleaning up the Dash.JS code and trying to understand it. I want to find the code that can process the received video into segments or frames. By which I mean, the encoder before playing video. So that I can add a module to enhance the quality of video.

Could you please help me find the part that can sovle my question? Thanks a lot.

Here is the architecture of Dash.JS: [Architecture of Dash.JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tSIY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Dash.js does not decode or render the video. It relies on the browsers Media Source Extensions for that. If you want to modify the rendered frames, you will need to render to a canvas and manipulate that.

Comment: But where that the received video from HTTP can be transferred to streaming?

Comment: media source buffer